# Phabricator: Auditing a commit before Phabricator Import failed to notify the commiter

Tags: svn, phabricator

I had a hard time describing the issue in the title.

I imported a SVN repo to Phabricator (on **Dec 22, 2014**). If I browse a commit added after the import in Audit, the committed field looks like this:

[image]

For commits from the same person before the import, it looks like:

[image]

I am not sure if this is a bug or a feature. How do I associate the old commits with the committer so when I raise a concern, the committer will receive an email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question in phabricator's own `Phabricator` bug report site.

Here is the [link](https://secure.phabricator.com/T6811) to that question. This behavior is by design but there is a function provided by phabricator that can help you fix the issue afterwards.